# Xamarin Forms - Update multiple views/pages when one property changes

Tags: xamarin.forms, view, binding, binding-context

I created a Xamarin forms application based on the tabbed page structure. There are around 5 tabs. 1 tabs has an entry. When I fill the entry, I want the other 4 tabs to show the entry in a label. How can I achieve this?

People usually say that you shouldn't bind multiple views to 1 viewmodel, each page should have it's own VM. If that's true, how can those views be updated? Should I refresh each tab when I navigate to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to synchronize data between viewmodels. I would have the viewmodel with the entry publish the new updated value via the [Xamarin Forms Messaging Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center).

The other tabs viewmodels can subscribe to these changes and update their properties accordingly